# can i pass object class that is inherited from template class?

Tags: c++, templates

How can i pass object that  inherited from template as this to function

please see the GameObj::GameObj constructor 
i try to pass the GameObj that is inheriting the BaseGameObject template
but its not valid

```
template<typename T>
class BaseGameObject 
{
    public:
        BaseGameObject(){};

        virtual ~BaseGameObject(){};

        static T* create(IImageComponent* imageComponent)
        {

        }
    protected:
        IImageComponent* m_IImageComponent;
};
class GameObj :public BaseGameObject<GameObj>  
{
    public:
        GameObj(IImageComponent* imageComponent);
        virtual ~GameObj(){};



};

GameObj::GameObj(IImageComponent* imageComponent):m_IImageComponent(imageComponent)
{

    m_IImageComponent->update(*this); //HERE IS THE PROBLEM IT ASK ME TO PASS TAMPLATE 
}
class GameObjImageCompnent
{
public :
    GameObjImageCompnent(const std::string &spritefilename);
    virtual void update(BaseGameObject& baseGameObject);


private:
    std::string m_spritefilename;
};

GameObjImageCompnent::GameObjImageCompnent(const std::string &spritefilename):
    m_spritefilename(spritefilename)
{
    ;
}
void GameObjImageCompnent::update(BaseGameObject& baseGameObject)
{

    baseGameObject.setInitWithSpriteFrameName(m_spritefilename);
}
```

this link doesn't work for me :
[Passing template classes as arguments to methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567856/passing-template-classes-as-arguments-to-methods)

Comment: what does class IImageComponent look like, especially the update() method signature?

Comment: its simple abstract class , with update as pure virtual 
but i dont know what should i set in the args as its not working

Comment: what is the method argument types for IImageComponent update()?  You are passing it GameObj object by dereferencing the this pointer in the GameObj constructor.  Is it looking for some object derived from the template BaseGameObject?

Comment: yes i do pass it , but i have different objects that are using the template and i can't pass from centeral point each time different class so i wanted to pass the baseclass that is template and its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BaseGameObject` is a template. `GameObjImageCompnent::update` has a declaration `virtual void update(BaseGameObject& baseGameObject);`. That's wrong because `BaseGameObject` is not a type but a template.

Maybe you should change that declaration to: `virtual void update(BaseGameObject<GameObj>& baseGameObject);`

If you need to be able to call that with different `BaseGameObject`s, you could make `GameObjImageCompnent` into a template as well:

```
template<class T>
class GameObjImageCompnent {
// ...
virtual void update(BaseGameObject<T>& baseGameObject);
```

If that's not an option, you probably need to inherit BaseGameObject from a non-template base class  and and use that as your reference type. If a base class for `BaseGameObject` is not an option either, you need to rethink your design.

```
class IGameObject {
public:
    virtual ~IGameObject() {}
    // any other virtual functions that are needed
};

template<typename T>
class BaseGameObject: public IGameObject {
//...

class GameObjImageCompnent {
// ...
virtual void update(IGameObject& baseGameObject);
```

You seem to be using [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). See the pitfalls section:

> One issue with static polymorphism is that without using a general base class like "Shape" from the above example, you cannot store your derived classes heterogeneously as each CRTP base class is a unique type. For this reason, it's likely that you'll want to inherit from a shared base class with a virtual destructor, like the example above.

I think that limitation also applies to passing objects of derived classes to a function through a heterogeneous reference.

Comment: `BaseGameObject` is a template. `BaseGameObject<T>` is a type. `BaseGameObject` is not a type, incomplete or otherwise.

Comment: I can't , its not allways GameObj in the template somtimes its other object

Comment: @user63898 then you shouldn't be using `template`s but runtime polymorphism (`virtual`s).

Comment: i want to keep 1 base class for different class types

Comment: @user63898: Okay but that's not what you have right now. Class templates are not classes!

Comment: @user63898 I've added suggestions to my answer.

Comment: wow great thanks i even didn't know there is pattern for this